# Как добавить клас в JQuery, а потом удалить его после клика

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, typescript, frontend

Помогите пожалуйста!!!
Привет!
Есть кнопка поиска. При нажатии на нее открывается поле для ввода текста.
Нужно сделать что бы при еще одного клика на эту кнопку поле опять пряталось.
Есть готовый скрипт для проявления поля, нужно добавить что бы reamove class заработало?

```
$(".fa-search").click(function () {
    $(".search").addClass("expand");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("div").click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("b");
});
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("div").toggle("show");
});
```

```css
div {
  color:red;
}

.b{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">toggle</button>
<div class="b">asdasd</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот, на чистом javascript:

```js
document.querySelector('.fa-search').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('.search').classList.toggle('expand')
}
```

```css
.search {
  display:none
}

input.expand {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<button class='fa-search'>search</button>
<input class='search'>
```

Вот, на Jquery:

```js
$(".fa-search").click(function () {
    $(".search").toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
.search {
  display:none
}

input.expand {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='fa-search'>search</button>
<input class='hidden search'>
```